# Why 4s lose electron to 3d?

Tags: electronic-configuration

In chromium and copper, the are the configuration fill up like
$$\mathrm{3d^5  4s^1}$$
but not $\mathrm{4s}$ first as it has lower energy level. and why only these 2 elements.

Comment: Copper doesn't have $3d^5$ in its base state, but a completely filled $d$ orbital.

Comment: If you've just only been recently introduced to the electron configurations, then an appropriate answer would be: "the half-filled 3d orbital in Cr and the completely filled 3d orbital in Cu are particularly stable". For a more detailed but also potentially very technical answer, look up *exchange energy*.

Comment: This is a very popular question in the chemistry world, and it has been asked and answered before: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151/why-do-elements-in-columns-6-and-11-assume-abnormal-electron-configurations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any element after Argon [1s<sup>2</sup>2s<sup>2</sup>2p<sup>6</sup>3s<sup>2</sup>3p<sup>6</sup>],
the repulsion force between the elctrons increase at a great extent and also the atom becomes very stable. So the elctrons tend to move in far 4s orbital first and after filling it completely , fill the 3d orbital. About chromium and copper, they are exceptions. Any half filled or fully-filled orbitals are more stable then rest of the configurations, so in Chromium one electron of 4s comes to 3d orbital and a stable 3d<sup>5</sup> is obtained, similarly in Copper one electron from 4s comes to 3d orbital and forms stable 3d<sup>10</sup>.

I hope this answers your question, 
If you have any further doubts you can ask me :)