# Elimination with Amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, halides

$\hspace{35 mm}$[image: Reaction]

## ATTEMPT:

Since $\ce{Et3N}$ is a weak base and the carbon to which $\ce{Br}$ is attached is tertiary, we can rule out $\mathrm{E2}$ and $\mathrm{S_N2}.$ As we are providing heat, the reaction is likely to go via $\mathrm{E1}$ forming a stable tertiary carbocation.

Now as the base is bulky it will knock out the most easily available $\ce{H}$, giving us the less substituted alkene.

However my text suggests that this reaction proceed via $\mathrm{E2}$ with the base taking a $\ce{H+}$ and knocking off $\mathrm{Br}$ to give the same final product.

In general with amines out of $\mathrm{E1}$ and $\mathrm{E2}$ which reaction is preferred if there is a possibility of stable carbocation formation?

Comment: Didn't you post this a couple of days ago? Why did you delete the first question and repost it?

Comment: @bon , The question was not getting enough attention.So i repost it.

Comment: @yasir You should not repost your question if it is not getting enough attention. Instead, use a bounty.

Comment: @wythagoras, I tried using a bounty on this.[Here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35086/exceptions-to-the-madelung-rule-for-electronic-configurations)But nothing happened.